# Android can't start launcher activity programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to implement such scheme: if in activity's `onCreate` i catch exception -> start launcher activity. I tried to do this in dif ways:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

but my app only closes. What is wrong?

Comment: did you try without setting category or flag to your intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ersin Gülbahar :

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
startActivity(startMain);
```

So simple.